# How to classify image and crop it using tensorflow?

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, image-recognition

I want to do something as follow 
1.I want to identify number plate from an image 
2.crop that image 
Using tensorflow 
Does anyone knows how to do it ?? 
If yes then please help me 
I haven't tried any code 
Help appreciated

Comment: Have tried with any code.? If yes please add to it question of add fiddle

Comment: @RahulMahadik yup updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get many open source libraries.

Please check with the following :

- [Number plate recognition with Tensorflow](https://matthewearl.github.io/2016/05/06/cnn-anpr/)  and Source code is
  [available here](https://github.com/matthewearl/deep-anpr).
- Also you can refer [this](https://github.com/AnjieZheng/Tensorflow-Number-Plate-Recognition)
- And another one which use OpenCV to [detect number plates in
  images](https://github.com/zubairahmed-ai/Number-Plate-Recognition)

You will get many.

Hope it help's you